# Best build tool for AngularJS frontend and Spring Framework backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, gradle, build.gradle

We are developing an application where we have AngularJS as Front-end and on Back-end we have Spring framework with hibernate, Rest web services etc. We are planning to use Gradle build for back-end but I am not sure that Gradle can be used for building AngularJS (compiling, minifying etc.). I did find JS and CSS plugins of Gradle but I dont know how much Gradle supports AngularJS (injection minification etc.)

We want to use a single build for both Front-end and Back-end. Please suggest what is the best way to achieve that with these technologies.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is more or less on what I'm working right now. To be precise I have an backend Spring build with Gradle and a frontend client written in AngularJS, but not build with Gradle. I need to marry this two projects using Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways could be to start with a project from [this blog](http://www.rnowak.info/2014/06/spring-boot-and-angularjs-quick-start.html). The project structure is not the best one there, but you can always change it your way. It is a single build project.

Another interesting post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001857/using-gradle-serve-a-front-end-js-and-a-backend-api-java). The Gradle file could be useful from the last post when you have problems with routing in AngularJS.

Comment: I am referring https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin.I am using many external scripts(jquery,angular,kendo etc) and loading them in index.html file using <script src> tag. Instead of loading all these scripts one by one I combined them in a single all.js using combineJs task.After replacing all the scripts with this single script my UI works fine.Then I minified all.js file with minifyJs task, it generated all.min.js and all.sourcemap.json.

Comment: But after raplacing all the scripts with all.min.js in index.html,my application does not work.It gave me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined" error. Do I also need to include all.sourcemap.json file in index.html.If yes then how.Or this error has something to do with Angular minification which might not have done properly by this task. Please guide.

Comment: I don't know if you read this article - http://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application . They seem to use different tool to generate kind of all.min.js. It might work but i didn't try it by myself.

Comment: @burseaner first link is dead. Can you please update the same.